# Directshow- ISampleGrabberCB::SampleCB callback frequency

Tags: directshow, video-capture

I am working on an application which requires video frame capture from different frame-grabber cards. I am using directshow `ISampleGrabberCB::SampleCB` callback to receive pointer to the new frame. Now I want to know when exactly this callback gets called ? Is it guaranteed that every time frame-grabber receives a new frame it will automatically get called ?

I was trying for 120Hz signals with various resolutions but I this callback is only getting called 50-55 times. So there is a possibility that my frame-grabber is not able to capture at that rate (although theoretically its capable). I want to find out whether this callback is bottleneck or framegrabber card.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SampleCB` is immediately called called from streaming thread, you have one call for every frame. While in callback, you block further streaming, that is you need to return control from your callback in order to resume (in particular, if your callback is "slow", it can reduce effective FPS).

Comment: I am doing nothing in my callback just receiving the pointer to data and information from VIDEOINFOHEADER and then incrementing a counter for frame-counting. After that control is returned immediately. 
I think it should not be that "slow".

With this information and your answer can I conclude that my frame-grabber is not receiving at higher rates ?

Comment: The only fact of presence of Sample Grabber might imply additional processing (filters in the topology), esp. if you, for instance, requested 24-bit RGB format for SG operation/callback. You should look at the entire filter graph to find out if there is anything else slowing things down.

Comment: If the Frame Grabber Card implements it, maybe the `IAMDroppedFrames` interfaces shows you if samples are dropped.